# Nginx listens at a port, only responds if set to port 80

Tags: configuration, nginx, funtoo

OS: Funtoo.
I have bound NGINX to port 81 (I want to run it alongside my Apache server for a short time for ease of transition), and it listens at the port (If I point at another port, using wget I get "Connection refused", but using port 81 I get "connected") but it never serves an HTML response of any kind!

When running a wget on the port, from the localhost, I get:

```
# wget localhost:81
-2014-04-16 23:56:45- http://localhost:81/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:81... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

On another computer...

```
$ wget 192.168.18.42:81
-2014-04-16 23:57:19- http://192.168.18.42:81/
Connecting to 192.168.18.42:81... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Nothing ever happens after that. The documents exist, it's the normal Funtoo nginx.conf.

UPDATE: I can make it listen to port 80, but it still rattles me that I can't get it to work on any port....

```
netstat -aWn | grep 81 | grep LISTEN
tcp 60 0 0.0.0.0:81 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

Edit:
Configuration files:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_rlimit_nofile 6400;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # This causes files with an unknown MIME type to trigger a download action in the browser:
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_max_body_size 64m;

    # Don't follow symlink if the symlink's owner is not the target owner.

    disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
    server_tokens off;
    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    gzip off;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js image/x-icon image/bmp;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    index index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Server block:

```
server {
    listen  *:81;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        index   index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a packet filter enabled (`iptables`)?  If so, did you remember to allow port 81?

Comment: iptables isn't enabled.

Comment: Then relevant parts of your configuration would be helpful, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the big problem? Nginx had set worker_processes to 0. I added a line setting it to `auto` in the top of my nginx.conf, and all was well with the world!

Thank you all for your time and patience.

Comment: You just saved me from giving up after about 1 hour of frustration—apparently one of my automated variables used for templating Nginx configuration output a `0` for `worker_processes`, and I was completely flabbergasted after quadruple-checking every other config file, DNS, hosts, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following server block:

```
server {
   listen       81 default_server;
    server_name _;    
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        index   index.html;
    }
}
```

The underscore `_` is a wildcard, Also the `*:81` likely doesn't do what you expect, just use the port number.

Then test your settings with `nginx -t`:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Restart nginx:

```
service nginx restart
```

Test with netstat:

```
root@gitlab:~# netstat -napl | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7903/nginx      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2662/unicorn.
```

---

**Update**

I installed nginx on a test system. With the stock `nginx.conf` file and a 1 line change to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, I was able to retrieve files from port 81

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server {

    listen   81;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Netstat output:

```
netstat -napl | grep 81
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3432/nginx
```

Download file:

```
$ wget localhost:81
```

Contents of file:

```
$ cat index.html
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<center><h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update2**

Test port:

```
 root@gitlab:# nc -vz localhost 81
 Connection to localhost 81 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
 root@gitlab:# nc -vz localhost 443
 nc: connect to localhost port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: `Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name`    


`tcp        9      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1026/nginx: master`  

Still no success. Is Recv-Q being 9 a hint of some sort? It goes up every time I try a wget or something like that. The server block is exactly as you prescribed.

Comment: I'm not sure what Recv-Q is. Do you have anything in /etc/nginx/sites-available ?

Comment: @T.C. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: no change to my status, even following the new config file. Is it possible there is something blocking ports not port 80? Is there a way I can test this?

Comment: T.C. yes, use nc, see update

Comment: Why still port 80 is in use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a websocket in the config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, you can see the whole configuration file for reverse proxy in https://help.teradici.com/s/article/1050

The magic part was adding:

```
upstream websocket {
    server <DESTINATION_IP>:<DEST_PORT>;
}
```